Ubuntu boots ok if choosing boot drive after pressing F11, otherwise hangs at "Loading initial ramdisk"
I've already drained over two weeks on this rack server that had been failing to boot. After trying many things (memory test, re-clone drive, reinstalling OS, upgrading BIOS, switching UEFI vs legacy boot, disabling fast boot in BIOS etc ...), I narrowed down the issue to the following

if I press F11 during BIOS POST, and chose the only boot drive (/dev/nvme0n1), the system boots and runs fine
however, if I let it boot automatically based on BIOS boot priorities (again, I only have one drive, /dev/nvme0n1), then, every grub boot option hangs at Loading initial ramdisk.

I've already modified /etc/default/grub to have (based on similar online discussions)
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="dis_ucode_ldr"

yet, still it does not help. Changing UEFI vs legacy boot has no impact to this difference. choosing different kernel versions also made no difference.
can someone help? what exactly is the difference if choosing the first boot disk from F11 boot menu, vs letting BIOS boot the first drive (which is literally the same drive)!
hardware is AsRock TRX40 Creator mobo, Threadripper 3990X CPU, 256GB memory, tried both Ubuntu 22.04 and 20.04, many installation and reinstallation and cloning, with no change of this behavior. very puzzling ...
[Update] The above behavior, i.e. "hangs at Loading initial ramdisk if boot BIOS default" is only shown for AsRock BIOS 1.85. If using BIOS v1.86, instead of hanging, kernels gave me a kernel panic - "BUG: unable to handle page fault for address fffffffffff4fd0b0", see below screenshot.
regardless of the BIOS version (1.85 or 1.86, or older ones), pressing F11 and choose the UEFI or legacy boot results in successful boot.


The only difference I can see is that your setup may be going to another UEFi? I would reset bios and if that did not solve the situation I would boot with live usb and check the UEFI partition and see what other partitions are there, there is also a possibibilty by pressing F11 you increase pre-boot time and whatever is needed comes on line.

I reflashed BIOS for various version, for some BIOS versions, kernel started showing kernel panic info again. Reverting to BIOS 1.85, the above observation is still reproducible. Using F11, I was able to boot Ubuntu. I ran efibootmgr -v, and noticed there are two efi files:
BootCurrent: 0001 Timeout: 1 seconds BootOrder: 0002,0001 Boot0001* ubuntu HD(1,MBR,0x9538fed1,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\GRUBX64.EFI) Boot0002* ubuntu HD(1,MBR,0x9538fed1,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)..BO  so I deleted the 2nd one, but still it did not solve the F11 issue.

regarding the suspicion that pressing F11 gives more pre-boot time, if I let it boot the default drive, and wait arbitrarily long in the grub menu, it still hangs at "loading initial ramdisk" step. I could not find any log on what is holding the booting process.

I added an update - using BIOS v1.86 produces a kernel panic instead of hanging. for either 1.85 or 1.86 BIOS version, pressing F11 allows the system to boot

Well I'm out of ideas maybe someone else can help, btw my efibootmagr -v has this BootCurrent: 0005,
Boot0005* Ubuntu HD(1,GPT,"some number" /File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI) and there are no MBR at all in the whole efibootmgr. There is no "MBR" in my efibootmgr, but I boot from SSD yours may be different, You can check the efibootmgr on the other computers.

This article may be interesting https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/linux-kernel-panic

@amar, thanks for sharing your efibootmgr -v output. My OS disks are formatted as MBR instead of GPT. For Linux, this should not be a problem as long as there is an EFI partition, see https://superuser.com/a/1067717/1766201. For my other working nodes, the efibootmgr output looks similar with MBR disk.
